# How to make R use all processors on hadoop cluster nodes?

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I have a R program that uses MapReduce(MR2) on hadoop cluster(7 nodes, 32cores CPU each ) to process the data. I configured the R program to use 10 reducers because I see the heavy lifting is done by reducers. However all these 10 reducers are using one cpu core at a time. So is there anyway I can make these reducers to use more than 1 cpu/per reducer?

Thanks,

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Comment: removed processing tag

Comment: What happens if you set the number of reducers to 32? Or -1? Or pi?

Comment: it might be related to your YARN config. Check http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_ig_yarn_tuning.html